# Create a Balanced Binary Search Tree with given a sorted list by passing the list to the sorting method in Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

As the title says, my goal is to print the preorder of the Balanced Binary Search Tree given a sorted (ascending) list.
The constraints are:

- sorted_array_to_bst() has to be a method of the TreeNode class
- the method takes as an argument the sorted list (not elements of the list iteratively)

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def sorted_array_to_bst(self, nums):
        def srt(nums):
            if not nums:
                return None
            mid_num = len(nums) // 2
            if self.val is None:
                self.val = nums[mid_num]
            # if self.val == nums[mid_num]:
            self.left = TreeNode(nums[:mid_num])
            self.right = TreeNode(nums[(mid_num + 1):])
        if self.val is None:
            srt(nums)

    def preorder(self, val):
        if self.val is not None:
            val.append(self.val)
        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.preorder(val)
        if self.right is not None:
            self.right.preorder(val)
        return val

node = TreeNode()
some_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
node.sorted_array_to_bst(some_list)
print(node.preorder([]))
```

for now the result is:
`[4, [1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]]`

it should be:
`[4, 2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 7]`

i tried sorting the left and right halves of the list:

```
            self.left = TreeNode(srt(nums[:mid_num]))
            self.right = TreeNode(srt(nums[(mid_num + 1):]))
```

but then the result is just `[4]`

Comment: *"As the title says, my goal is to print the preorder"* - Uh... actually the title doesn't say anything about printing or preorder. It instead talks about creating the tree. What is it you truly desire? The tree or the preorder? Or both?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you call the `TreeNode` constructor with a list as argument:

```
        self.left = TreeNode(nums[:mid_num])
        self.right = TreeNode(nums[(mid_num + 1):])
```

Instead, you should apply recursion, and call `sorted_array_to_bst` recursively.

Another issue is that it makes no sense that `sorted_array_to_bst` is defined as an *instance* method. You should not need to first create a (dummy) node. Instead define it as a *class* method. Moreover, nodes should only be created for real data and there should not be some special virtual nodes that have `None` as value. `None` might actually be a value you want to assign to a real node.

Not related to your question, but it is unnatural that you have to provide an argument to your `preorder` function. It should do the job without that argument. In fact, make it a generator.

Here is a working implementation:

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    @classmethod
    def sorted_array_to_bst(Cls, nums):
        if not nums:
            return None
        
        mid_num = len(nums) // 2
        root = Cls(nums[mid_num])
        root.left = Cls.sorted_array_to_bst(nums[:mid_num])
        root.right = Cls.sorted_array_to_bst(nums[(mid_num + 1):])
        return root

    def preorder(self):
        yield self.val
        if self.left:
            yield from self.left.preorder()
        if self.right:
            yield from self.right.preorder()


some_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
node = TreeNode.sorted_array_to_bst(some_list)
print(*node.preorder())
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? Can you give some feed-back?